# Using environment variables in if-else statement in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkins, I've created a pipeline to go through several stages. In the second stage, after cloning the repository in the first stage, I want to check if a file called `${FILENAME}` exists in the `${REPOSITORY_NAME}/apps` directory.

If it exists, I want to perform `kubectl rollout restart deployment ${APPLICATION_NAME}`, and if it does not exist, I want to create such application.

I am not used to Jenkins' environment variables, and having trouble using it for the condition in the if-else statement.

Even when the `${FILENAME}` exists, `env.ALREADY_EXISTS` won't change to `"true"`; however I've confirmed that `echo "ALREADY_EXISTS = ${ALREADY_EXISTS}"` results in `ALREADY_EXISTS = true`.

Why is `env.ALREADY_EXISTS` not updated and how can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
      APPLICATION_NAME="myapp"
      REPOSITORY_NAME="myrepo"
      FILENAME="${APPLICATION_NAME}-app.yaml"
      ALREADY_EXISTS="false"
    }
    stages {
        stage("Clone Git Repository") {
            steps {
                git(
                    url: "https://github.com/myid/${REPOSITORY_NAME}.git",
                    branch: "main",
                    changelog: true,
                    credentialsId: 'mycreds',
                    poll: true
                )
            }
        }
        stage("Check if file already exists") {
            steps {
                sh '''
                  cd ./apps
                  if [ -f "${FILENAME}" ]; then
                    echo "${FILENAME} exists"
                    ALREADY_EXISTS="true"
                  else
                    echo "${FILENAME} does not exist"
                    ALREADY_EXISTS="false"
                  fi
                  echo "ALREADY_EXISTS = ${ALREADY_EXISTS}"
                  cd ..
                '''
            }
        }
        stage("Rollout or create app") {
            steps {
                script {
                    if (env.ALREADY_EXISTS == "true") {
                        withKubeConfig([namespace: "${APPLICATION_NAME}-${CLIENT_ID}"]) {
                            sh 'curl -LO https://dl.k8s.io/release/v1.26.3/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl'
                            sh 'chmod u+x ./kubectl'
                            sh './kubectl rollout restart deployment ${APPLICATION_NAME}'
                        }
                    } else {
                      sh '''
                        # Create new app ...
                      '''
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set environment variables or pipeline variables from within `sh` blocks. Here is how you can do this. Following is a simplified version using [fileExists](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#fileexists-verify-if-file-exists-in-workspace) utility step.

```
def fExists = false

pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Stage 1') {
      steps {
        script {
            sh 'echo "test" >> file.txt'
            def exists = fileExists 'file.txt'
            if(exists){
                echo "File exists"
                fExists = true
            }
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Stage 2') {
      steps {
        script {     
            echo "$fExists"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```